# EWS adding calendar to someone elses account

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to add a new appointment to someone else exchange account using EWS.  I'm trying to do this from a web server.  I've got code working that will add the info to the account that is logged into the server but can't figure out how to add an appointment to someone else account.  I think i'm getting hung up because of the Exchange service credentials.  I thought perhaps if i passed in the credentials of the administrator that i would be able to add to someones account but that isn't working either.  Was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction.  Here is the code i have working to add the appointment to my own calendar.

Thanks
Shannon

```
Friend Shared Function GetService(emailAddress As String) As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
    Dim Service As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService = Nothing
    Try
        Service = New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
        ' Microsoft recommends to use AutoDiscoverUrl to ensure that always the best endpoint for the given user is used.
        Service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress)
        Service.UseDefaultCredentials = True


        Service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("administrator", "password", "domain.com")
    Catch ex As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException
        'Seems that user does not work on Exchange 2007 SP1 or later?
    End Try
    Return Service
End Function
Private Sub TestIt()
    Try
        'Create appointment object and set properties as required
        'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress
        Dim appt As Appointment = New Appointment(GetService("jim@domain.com"))
        appt.Subject = "Holidays"
        appt.Body = "The appointment is for holiday placeholder"
        appt.Start = Now()
        appt.End = appt.Start.AddHours(24)
        appt.IsAllDayEvent = True
        appt.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = LegacyFreeBusyStatus.OOF
        appt.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim x As String
        x = ""
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I thought perhaps if i passed in the credentials of the administrator that i would be able to add to someones account but that isn't working either.

As a general rule that won't work because Admin accounts don't have rights to users mailboxes for privacy and security reasons. Rights to Mailboxes always need to explicitly granted eg Add-MailboxPermission (or Add-MailboxFolderPermissions) to the TargetMailbox. One thing you can do is grant a Service account (don't use the admin account) impersonation rights https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx and then change your code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx .

One thing you should change in your code regardless is

```
 appt.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)
```

Using the FolderId overload where you specify the Mailbox you want to save the appointment to will mean your code will be more consistent regardless of the authentication mode you use (the above will always save to the security principal your using mailbox)

```
Dim SaveToFolderId As New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "Mailbox@domain.com")
appt.Save(SaveToFolderId, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)
```